# TextView text color does not change

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the text color of a `TextView`. This is the code I am using:

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eks"

    />
```

Java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));  }
```

Any ideas why the text color is not changing?

Comment: write only txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE). it should work.if its not working check you may set a wrong content view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eks"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

try this

Comment: @Vennu you have to wait some time before you can accept it:P I ll dont worry

Answer (score 3):

If you use the extend of theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`,
color of the `TextView` can't change any more.

Comment: can you say why ?

Comment: what to do than?

Comment: I hate this fact

Comment: I'm using 
Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Android Resources system to get everything jiving all nice and pretty.

## /res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

## /res/layout/my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eks"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```